# SQL sum of max values of single days of the week (starting from monday to sunday)

Tags: sql, date

I'm using the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(Ener) AS enTot
        FROM (
            SELECT MAX(Ener) as en, WEEKDAY(DateTime) as day
            FROM $dailyTable
            WHERE WEEK(DATE(DateTime)) = WEEK(DATE('$today'), 1)
            AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DateTime)) >= 0
            AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DateTime)) <= 6
            GROUP BY day
        ) AS subquery;";
```

it works as expected but the final result is a sum of max values of days from *Sunday to Saturday*. Instead, I want from *Monday to Sunday*.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with using `WEEK` for grouping because of the incomplete week in the end of the year. I would rather use *last Monday before(including) today* as the grouping parameter.

Last Monday can be calculated from the given `DateTime` value with the following expression:

```
CAST(DATEADD(day, -((DATEPART(weekday, DateTime) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7), DateTime) AS DATE) AS LastMonday
```

The full query could look like:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Ener) AS enTot
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(Ener) as en, WEEKDAY(DATEADD(day, -1, DateTime)) as day
    FROM $dailyTable
    WHERE CAST(DATEADD(day, -((DATEPART(weekday, DateTime) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7), DateTime) AS DATE) =
          CAST(DATEADD(day, -((DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7), GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    GROUP BY day
) AS subquery;
```

My first thought was to use `DATEADD(day, -1, DateTime)` instead of `DateTime` and
`DATEADD(day, -1, '$today')` instead of `'$today'` to "convert" Sunday to Saturday so that it belongs to the previous week.
Then the WEEKDAY conditions look redundant. **But that might have the above mentioned problem with incomplete week.**

Also this calculation depends on [SET DATEFIRST 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) option.