# Distinct New Customers in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The table below has customer ID, product purchased, and purchase date.

```
customer_id products    purchase_date
93738117783 product a   5/24/2022
93738117783 product a   6/8/2022
93738117783 product a   7/19/2022
93738117783 product a   8/18/2022
93738117783 product a   9/22/2022
93738117783 product a   10/19/2022
93738117783 product a   11/17/2022
93738117783 product a   12/27/2022
93738554027 product a   5/5/2021
93738738408 product b   8/2/2021
93738738408 product b   9/20/2021
93738738408 product b   10/26/2021
93738738408 product b   12/2/2021
93738738408 product b   1/2/2022
93738738408 product b   3/27/2022
93738738408 product b   5/2/2022
93738738408 product b   6/10/2022
93738738408 product b   7/8/2022
93738738408 product b   7/31/2022
93738117783 product a   8/1/2022
93738117783 product a   9/5/2022
93738117783 product a   10/8/2022
93738117783 product a   11/16/2022
93738117783 product a   12/19/2022
93738943799 product a   10/21/2020
93738943799 product a   11/20/2020
93738943799 product a   1/24/2021
93739310547 product b   5/3/2022
93739310547 product b   8/19/2022
93739310547 product b   1/5/2023
```

From this table, I want to create a SQL query to get the following output -

```
product a   new_customers   week_ending_Friday
product a   2               12/16/2022
product b   3               12/16/2022
product a   1               12/10/2022
product b   4               12/10/2022
```

new_customers = new to purchasing the product in 1yr from the purchase_date
week_ending_Friday = date rolled upto week ending friday

Any idea will help me.

Comment: select count(*) grouped by products ..... For the "week ending friday" you might need to share which DBMS you use (as requestion in the description of [tag:sql]), because the implementation WEEK can change between different DBMS's

Comment: Im using Snowflake. new_customers = new to purchasing the product in 1yr from the purchase_date

Comment: BTW: the 10th december of 2022 is a different day than the 16th december of that year.

Comment: If you need to group by week, then please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75174111/822455. It contains the expression to calculate the previous Monday, but you can easily update it to find Fridays.

Answer (score 2):

First step: get a date's week's Friday. By ISO definition a week starts on Monday, so you'll have to add 4 days to the ISO week's start day to get Friday.

<strike>DATE_TRUNC('weekiso', purchase_date) + INTERVAL '4 day'</strike>

Correction: The general [docs on date and time functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html) in snowflake show that `weekiso` is not allowed with `DATE_TRUNC`. This is a pity, for this means we must find out how many days to add to the purchase date. I think this should do the trick:

```
purchase_date + (interval '1 day' * (5 - date_part(dayofweekiso, purchase_date)))
```

Then, in order to find new customers, we would get the first purchse day per customer and product, a simple aggregation, but in your comments you say that you also consider a customer new, when their last puchase was made more than a year before. So, we need a lookup, which we do with `[NOT] EXISTS`.

```
select
  day as week_ending_friday,
  product,
  count_if(is_new) as new_customers
from
(
  select
    customer_id,
    product,
    purchase_date +
      (interval '1 day' * (5 - date_part(dayofweekiso, purchase_date))) as day,
    not exists
    (
      select null
      from purchases pp
      where pp.customer_id = p.customer_id
      and pp.product = p.product
      and pp.purchase_date < p.purchase_date
      and pp.purchase_date >= p.purchase_date - interval '1 year'
    ) as is_new
  from purchases p
) evaluated
group by day, product
order by day, product;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time! somehow date_trunc is showing an error, will check out alternatives. I was meaning, new customer in a week = should not have a purchase record in the past 1yr to qualify to be a new customer for a particular week

Comment: typically the first record for a customer is a new customer, if the following purchase dates are within a year of first purchase, they should be removed

Comment: In your comments you said "new_customers = new to purchasing the product in 1yr from the purchase_date". This is what the query checks, so this should be exactly what you want. As to the error: This is strange. What error are you getting?

Comment: Snowflake's DATE_TRUNC depends on the session setting for WEEK_START, so it is not safe to add four days. You'd have to determine which day WEEK_START is set to in order to add the appropriate number of days.

Comment: @Adrian White: Haha. This is what I told you regarding your using 
 `DATE_TRUNC('week', ...)`. I am using `DATE_TRUNC('weekiso', ...)` for this very reason. An ISO week starts with Monday (as I have explained in my answer) regardless of any settings. (But, anyway, the OP said they are getting an error with `DATE_TRUNC`. I am still waiting for them to tell us which error.)

Comment: Some options to fix ...  use just weekiso() , change date_trunc() by adding interval based on   dayofweekiso().  Which do you think is best? select DATE_TRUNC('week', current_date() )  week_number , weekiso(current_date()), dayofweekiso(current_date())

Comment: Thank you @Adrian White. Adding an interval based on `dayofweekiso` should do the trick. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The [qualify](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) bit :

`datediff(day,coalesce(lag(purchase_date)over(partition by customer_id,products order by purchase_date)+365,purchase_date),purchase_date)>=0`

This identifies if the customer is new for this product. As the requirements define new to include over 1 year ago (+365) we need to grab the previous purchase ([lag](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html)) and see how many days previous this was. I defaulted 0 if it's actually the very first purchase, meaning I can add +365 to the [datediff](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html)  and anything 0 and above is either brand new or over 1 year since the previous purchase.

I prefer the qualify approach over nested queries as the SQL looks more elegant, and I'm a lazy typist (ask Thorsten Kettner). The other answer by Thorsten uses almost 50% word/functions etc.  However if you find the readability better -> that's the solution for you. So (1) find SQL you can read, (2) choose the understandable SQL with least chars.

The array functions [array_agg()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) and [array_size()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_size.html) are pretty cool - have a look at the Snowflake docs they're pretty self explanatory - reach back if you have any questions. I prefer to link to the docs as Snowflake is always fiddling with these functions so the docs can change. Note - I've never seen them break stuff -> but they sometimes add functionality.

The reason I add the cte at the front of the code - is so when smarter folks than I come and look at answers they can copy/paste into Snowflake and get the example working asap. This means we're not wasting their time - quite often actual Snowflake employees answer questions so it's best to make things quick and easy for them to improve answers.  I'd recommend all questions have this -> as you're likely to get more answers.

```
with cte as (select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '5/24/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '6/8/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '7/19/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '8/18/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '9/22/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '10/19/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '11/17/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '12/27/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738554027 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '5/5/2021'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '8/2/2021'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '9/20/2021'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '10/26/2021'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '12/2/2021'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '1/2/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '3/27/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '5/2/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '6/10/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '7/8/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738738408 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '7/31/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '8/1/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '9/5/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '10/8/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '11/16/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738117783 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '12/19/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738943799 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '10/21/2020'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738943799 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '11/20/2020'::date purchase_date
union all select 93738943799 customer_id, 'product a' products,   '1/24/2021'::date purchase_date
union all select 93739310547 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '5/3/2022'::date purchase_date
union all select 93739310547 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '8/19/2020'::date purchase_date
union all select 93739310547 customer_id, 'product b' products,   '1/5/2023'::date purchase_date)

 select   
  DATE_TRUNC('week', purchase_date) + INTERVAL '4 day' week_number
 ,products
 ,array_unique_agg(customer_id)over (partition by week_number, products) new_custs
 ,array_size(new_custs) number_new_custs
from cte 
qualify 
    datediff(day,coalesce(lag(purchase_date)over(partition by customer_id,products order by purchase_date)+365,purchase_date),purchase_date)>=0
```

Comment: Snowflake's [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) depends on the session setting for [WEEK_START](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-week-start), so it is not safe to add four days. You'd have to determine which day `WEEK_START` is set to in order to add the appropriate number of days.

Comment: And please don't post code-only answers. Explain what your query does to solve the given task.

Comment: It is great you have added an explanation. I see that snowflake allows using an alias in the same clause where it is defined, which standard SQL does not. This allows for shorter code. I also like the idea of using `LAG` to check the one-year rule. What I don't understand, though, is how you get from date and customer in the rows to date only in the result. If two customers buy at the exact same dates, how do you get to rows per date? Your `QUALIFY` clause would have to get rid of one customer's rows while keeping the other's, which I think your clause does not.

Comment: The array :
array_unique_agg(customer_id)over (partition by week_number, products) 

is partitioned by weeknumber    @Thorsten Kettner